# Create pull request for specific commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to push a specific commit to master and I am using cherry-pick for this.

```
- git checkout master
- git cherry-pick 35ea91db5ce
- git push origin master
```

But last command throws error that

> remote: Branch refs/heads/master can only be modified through pull requests.
>   remote: Check your branch permissions configuration with the project administrator.

Is there any way to create pull request for a specific commit?

I can do this using GUI/eclipse also if there is a way.

Comment: from the `git` commands, what I can see is you directly push to the `master` branch?

Comment: step by step explanation https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the master branch is configured to only be modified through pull requests, in other words, direct pushes aren't accepted. You need to push to a "temporary" branch (something like a "development" or "feature" branch) and then ask for a pull request using the "Create pull request" button at the Bitbucket repository's page. This temporary branch can be at the same repository or in a forked repository.